# Postgres: Physical and logical replication on one server

Tags: postgresql, replication, logical-replication

We are planning to get Postgres 13 version server.

We want to have one master server, which will get data
from various servers using logical replication. On this server,
using procedure we'll transform data.
Additional to this
we plan to have slave server, which will get get physical replication from master.
Queries will be executed on slave server.

So the question is - if something happens and slave becomes master, how
can we replace logical replicas from master to slave?

Can slave server get physical replication data and logical at the same time?
I guess not.
How its better in this situation?
We want to switch from master to slave immediately and continue to get logical replication
data from another servers

Any advices? What solutions do you suggest?